# Distance between labels using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 3.18.

It is necessary that the labels are evenly spaced relative to each other and do not clump together.

Where can I specify the parameter in the settings: the distance (buffer) between the labels?

[image]
[image]

Comment: QGIS 3.18 has been rolled back to 3.16. Before you try to dig into resolving your question, you may want to download and use QGIS 3.16. https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: Are the red arrows showing where you want the labels to be? They don't exist on your map?

Comment: Yes. With red arrows, I wanted to show how I want to move the labels

Comment: I understand that it is an extremely difficult task for QGIS